# Ubuntu 14.04 audio not heard(dummy output)

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in my PC. The sound setting is set to "dummy Output" and I can't hear any sound through my speakers and headset. I tried many trouble shooting methods but none of them are working. This is what i get when I try to install Alsamixer

```
x@y-desktop:~$ sudo apt install alsamixer
[sudo] password for x: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alsamixer


x@y-desktop:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory

x@y-desktop:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

What should I do to get sound output ??

Comment: When you run `killall pulseaudio`, does the sound work or not?

Comment: nope...no change

Comment: Please do the following to test, click on: System Settings -> Sound -> Test Sound (Speaker test, Not Digital Output (S/PDIF) test) ?

Comment: still no change....
"Speaker Testing for dummy output"  left and right speakers were tested .

Comment: Please check here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: @DnrDevil That was out of date in 2012, doesn't help anymore

Comment: @TshilidziMudau This is year 2017 and it really helped me thanks a lot you are a savior

Comment: Haha, I'm glad I could help :). I will also copy my comment to the answers section below in the hopes of helping others.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic sound troubleshooting guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting).

To reinstall back to the official drivers open a terminal and type

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

then update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Please try trouble shooting first.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question I know but for the sake of completeness, here is what I suggested on the comment above which is helpful for a couple of people:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

Then do the following to test, click on: *System Settings -> Sound -> Test Sound* (Speaker test, Not Digital Output (S/PDIF) test.